# Why are linear regression models used for things like pricing or modeling a response that can only be positive?

Tags: regression

A lot of pricing models, e.g., in finance, use linear regression. Price, by definition, is nonnegative, but linear regression doesn't constrain the model to positive values only. So, is its use actually valid? In practice, what happens when a model predicts negative values for a response that can't be negative?

Comment: Predicted values $\hat Y_j$ in regression on several variables $x_i$ are not of much use if based on values $x_{ij}$ that lie outside the range of the data for those variables. So if predictor and predicted variables are all relevant to positive $Y$'s, then it is natural to predict for positive values $\hat Y_j.$ // However, regression is also used to predict both increases (+) and decreases (-). So there is no theoretical preference for predicting positive quantities/ One predicts what is of interest and what available data permit.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is its use actually valid?

OLS has the advantage of being simple to estimate and interpret. Simplicity is a big point in favor of any tool.

And no, it is quite obviously not perfectly "valid". But neither is, most likely, any other tool we apply. We will assume linearity in predictors (or in predictors transformed in *one specific way*), we will assume that we have the correct predictors and no more, we will assume that we have modeled the error structure correctly, and so forth. All of these are quite heroic assumptions, and a modeler should have the humility to understand that their model likely does not reflect reality fully. The shortcomings of OLS are just a little more obvious than those of other models.

Remember Box' quote (Box & Draper, 1987, p. 424): "All models are wrong, but some are useful." It's a question of whether your OLS is so wrong that it is not useful any more. It can be correct enough to be useful across a wide range of positive prices.

And yes, of course there are modelers out there who simply have never gone beyond OLS and are not aware of its shortcomings. OLS is their hammer, and every problem looks like a nail to them.

> In practice, what happens when a model predicts negative values for a response that can't be negative?

I would say that this is a indication that the model is not useful any more.

What happens then is that people ask here at CrossValidated, and they get pointed to more appropriate models (or they get a recommendation to talk to a real-life statistician).

Comment: Yes, I agree. No model is ever perfectly valid. There's always assumptions that are never 100% satisfied, and the point is to assess the degree to which they're not satisfied and how concerning that is. This post was actually motivated by some comments (not really relevant at all to the question I posed there) left in my stackoverflow post where the person is saying that it doesn't make sense to create a linear model against "count" data because one of the assumptions is that residuals follow a normal distribution and distribution of counts is discrete and non-negatie, so regression model...

Comment: ...may produce negative predicted values, which are theoretically impossible.

Comment: I get that it's "theoretically impossible," but there are a lot of things that we assume that are "theoretically" impossible. Assuming normality of residuals is generally impossible to 100% satisfy, so I'm not sure what this person was trying to get at.

Comment: Yes indeed. I do sales forecasting for a living. Supermarket sales are inherently counts. At sufficiently high aggregation (e.g., weekly movements out of a distribution center), the time series can be well modeled using OLS and ignoring the count characteristics. At lower granularities (e.g., daily sales per SKU and store), almost everything needs to be treated as count data and modeled, e.g., using Poisson regression.

Comment: Regardless of the count characteristics, aren't time series data, which I have no experience in, not appropriate for OLS due to autocorrelation between the residuals? I would have thought that'd be too significant of a violation of OLS to use it in any meaningful way?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice... well, we did a good enough job to have been doing this for over twenty years now, so we must be doing *something* right. I like to say that most of the autocorrelation in retail sales is really weekly or yearly seasonality, which can be modeled using dummies. And other drivers, like promotions, are far more important than either seasonality or remaining "true" autocorrelation. And these can be more easily modeled using some kind of regression than using ARIMAX or similar. More here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUlToPvftFw

Comment: @StephanKolassa - I watched your video and have a related question on forecasting using regression. Is this something that you would be able to help me with? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596295/predict-positive-values-only-regression-best-practices